# using strlen in array declaration

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, declaration, strlen

I wrote the following code :

```
char arrA[] = "something.";
char arrB[ strlen(arrA) + 5];
```

And my code behaves vaguely. I am getting the wrong output. First, according to me the problem would be the use of `strlen` in array declaration. As memory is allocated while compile time and functions are executed at run time. But I didn't get the error at run time. My code compiled correctly but it is not working as I thought it would be. The best part is I am not using these array anywhere in my code. I am just declaring them.
 **Why I got no error at compile time ?**
 **Why my code output is unexpected ?**

When I comment this second declaration I get the correct output.
I also tried to print the `sizeof` `arrB`. Guess what I got *15*.
This means it is working correctly. But output is a mess and it should not be working correctly.
**What is happening here. Why the thing which I am only declaring, not using anywhere affects my code badily?**

My actual code is too big and is different. It would be impossible to explain this error using that code. But I am sharing that code also. This problem in my code is in the function `portClearer` and for the array `completeCommand`.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int strintToInt(char *str, int len);
void read_command_output(char*, char*, int);
void processIdFinder(char*);
void portClearer(char*);
void compileRegex(regex_t*, char*);
void executeRegex(regex_t*, char*, size_t, regmatch_t*, int);

int main()
{   
    processIdFinder("dispatcher");
    portClearer("4444");
    return 0;
}

void read_command_output(char* command, char* buf, int buf_len){

    FILE *ps_output_file;
    if ((ps_output_file = popen(command,"r"))== NULL){
        printf("error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(fgets(buf, buf_len, ps_output_file)==NULL)
        printf("%s\n",buf);

    fclose(ps_output_file);

    return;
}

void compileRegex(regex_t* regexPtr, char* pattern){

    if( regcomp(regexPtr, pattern, REG_EXTENDED) ){ 
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        exit(1); 
    }
}

void executeRegex(regex_t* regex, char* buf, size_t nmatch, regmatch_t* reg_matches, int flags){

    char errmsgbuf[100];
    int err_ret;
    err_ret = regexec(regex, buf, nmatch, reg_matches, flags);
    if( !err_ret ){
        //puts("Match");
        return;    
    }
    else if( err_ret == REG_NOMATCH ){
            puts("No match");
            exit(1);
    }
    else{
            regerror(err_ret, regex, errmsgbuf, sizeof(errmsgbuf));
            fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", errmsgbuf);
            exit(1);
    }
}

int strintToInt(char *str, int len)
{
    int iter, pow_iter, num=0;
    for(iter = 0, pow_iter = len-1; iter < len; iter++, pow_iter--)
    {
        num += (str[iter]-48)* ((int) pow(10,pow_iter));
    }
    return num;

}

void processIdFinder(char* commandName){

    char buf[100], id_proc[10];
    regex_t regex;
    regmatch_t reg_matches[2];

    char command[] = "/bin/ps -C ", commandGrep[] = " | grep ";
    char completeCommand[ strlen(command) + strlen(commandGrep) + 2 * 12];
    //"/bin/ps -C supervisor | grep supervisor"

    strcpy(completeCommand, command);
    strcat(completeCommand, commandName);
    strcat(completeCommand, commandGrep);
    strcat(completeCommand, commandName);

    read_command_output(completeCommand, buf, 100);

    compileRegex(&regex, "^ *([1-9]+) ?");

    executeRegex(&regex, buf, (size_t) 2, reg_matches, 0);

    //fetching result
    //printf("%d and %d  ----- %c and %c\n",reg_matches[1].rm_so,reg_matches[1].rm_eo,buf[reg_matches[1].rm_so],buf[reg_matches[1].rm_eo - 1]);
    strncpy(id_proc,buf+reg_matches[1].rm_so, reg_matches[1].rm_eo - reg_matches[1].rm_so);
    printf("(%s)\n",id_proc);
    printf("%d\n",strintToInt(id_proc,strlen(id_proc))); //its important to write strlen here not 10

    return;
}

void portClearer( char* portNo){

    char buf[100], id_proc[10];
    regex_t regex;
    regmatch_t reg_matches[2];

    char command[] = "/bin/netstat -nlp | grep ";
    char completeCommand[ strlen(command) + 5 ]; 
    //char completeCommand[ 25 + 5 ]; 
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(completeCommand));

    //strcpy(completeCommand, command);
    //strcat(completeCommand, portNo);

    read_command_output("/bin/netstat -nlp | grep 4444", buf, 100);

    compileRegex(&regex, "[1-9]+/");

    executeRegex(&regex, buf, (size_t) 1, reg_matches, 0);

    //fetching result
    //printf("%d and %d  ----- %c and %c\n",matches[0].rm_so,matches[0].rm_eo,buf[matches[0].rm_so],buf[matches[0].rm_eo - 1]);
    strncpy(id_proc,buf+reg_matches[0].rm_so, reg_matches[0].rm_eo - reg_matches[0].rm_so-1);
    printf("(%s)\n",id_proc);
    printf("%d\n",strintToInt(id_proc,strlen(id_proc))); //its important to write strlen here not 10

    return;
}
```

Comment: `strlen("something.")` is 10, so `sizeof(arrB)` should be 15...

Comment: Is C99 support enabled in the compiler?

Comment: Your code behaves "vaguely"?? What does that mean?

Comment: You are aware, that you always need to allocate one more character then your string actually should contain, for storing the trailing 0-terminator? With the current code probelms will occur for 5-digit port numbers for example.

Comment: @Kerrek, I am not getting the same output when I commented the array declaration line. (and I am not using this array)

Comment: @alk Yes I am aware of this.
@hmjd My gcc version is `gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1`.   I don't know how to check which c version it is using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variable length array (which were introduced in C99):

```
char completeCommand[ strlen(command) + 5 ];
```

which explains why it compiles if your compiler has C99 support enabled.

This is incorrect:

```
if(fgets(buf, buf_len, ps_output_file)==NULL)
    printf("%s\n",buf);
```

as it is using `buf` in the event that `fgets()` fails (and is the probable cause of the output being a mess). It should be:

```
if(fgets(buf, buf_len, ps_output_file)!=NULL)
    printf("%s\n",buf);
```

Note that [`strncpy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) does not append a null terminator, but *may* copy it from the source buffer to the destination buffer. This means it is not guaranteed that `id_proc` will be null terminated. If `id_proc` is not null terminated and passed to `printf("%s")` garbage will most likely appear after the content of `id_proc`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing `fgets` mistake.  
For array You haven't answered my question.  
Because I am getting wrong output.

Comment: And it is not the cause of the mess as this is not printing in the output

Comment: I almost always (used to) use snprintf instead of strncpy, like `char buf[5]; snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s", other_c_string);` (of course needing to to take care that buf is actually char array before using sizeof like that). Feel free to augment your answer if you agree with this use.

Comment: Yeah I agree with all these things but why this thing is changing my output if I am not using the strings(which i used in strcpy...) anywhere else in my code. they have no role in the output.

Comment: @knoxxs, because the `id_proc` may not be null terminated the presence of the variable may be affecting the content of the memory around the `id_proc` array. This could cause the (undefined) behaviour change. ensure `id_proc` is null terminated and retry with and without.